# Transferring data between Django projects

Tags: django

I have two Django projects with similar apps, and I need to transfer/transform data from one app (@djangoproject1) to another (@djangoproject2). My script to access both projects/databases (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644684/in-django-how-do-i-query-a-separate-project-from-within-my-main-project)) looks like this

```
import os
import sys
from django.apps import apps

sys.path.append('/django/djangoproject1')
sys.path.append('/django/djangoproject2')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoproject1.settings")
from djangoproject1 import settings

apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 
from app1.models import Page
mypage = Page.objects.get(id=1234)
print(mypage.title)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoproject2.settings")
from djangoproject2 import settings

apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 
from app2.models import Page
mypage = Page.objects.get(id=3421)
print(mypage.title)
```

It fails importing the model Page from app2, referring to the first model in models.py:

`RuntimeError: Model class app2.models.FirstModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

If the configuration for one project (either djangoproject1 or djangoproject2) is commented out, the script works fine (printing the respective page's title). How can I load the database content from one project/app, then switch to the other project/app properly?

To clarify: The table in the target app is already populated, so I need to insert the data from the source app creating new ids. Then again, one of the ForeignKeys in the table points to existing entries, and this relation needs to be kept intact. I hope to select the top-level entry first, insert it into the new table, then work forward using the new id as parent key for its immediate descendants etc.

Comment: If two separate projects need to transfer data, it is likely a better choice & more secure choice to use an `API` to do this. You can use `django-rest-framework` for this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: This is a one-time data transfer done locally (on my development machine), so security is not an issue. I just need to access the first database, extract some of the entries, transform them and feed them to the second database. The older django project will be archived afterwards.

Comment: Why not do this at the database level then?

Comment: I would like to use the Django ORM for the transformation.